# WSO2 - Error while testing echo service with SOAP (custom proxy)

Tags: soap, service, proxy, wso2, echo

I'm pretty new to WSO2 world, I'm trying to create a custom proxy service with Payload and SEND.
I am using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

This is `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Test_02_ESBCPSendPayLoad"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://wso2:8282/services/echo"/>
      </endpoint>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="LOG1" value="LOG1"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <echo:echoInt xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
                  <in>$1</in>
               </echo:echoInt>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"
                    evaluator="xml"
                    expression="//*[local-name()='return']"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full" separator=",">
            <property name="LOG2" value="LOG2"/>
         </log>
         <log level="custom" separator=",">
            <property name="LOG3" value="LOG3"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="custom" separator=":">
            <property name="LOG4" value="LOG4"/>
         </log>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://wso2:8282/services/echo?wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

`
While I'm trying to test it with SOAP I got this error:

> TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-06-25 10:19:37,651] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -
>   {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

That's why I guess :

> INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To:
>   /services/Test_02_ESBCPSendPayLoad.Test_02_ESBCPSendPayLoadHttpSoap11Endpoint:WSAction: urn:echoInt:SOAPAction: urn:echoInt:MessageID:
>   urn:uuid:c8941529-7a84-46b1-9981-d6596d35de49:Direction:
>   request:LOG2 =
>   LOG2:Envelope: 
>   {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}

This is the SOAP request:

```
> <soapenv:Envelope 
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
> xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">   
> </soapenv:Header>
> <soapenv:Body>
>       <echo:echoInt>
>          <!--Optional:-->
>          <in>1</in>
>       </echo:echoInt>    
> </soapenv:Body> 
> </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could someone help me ?

Thank you!

Claudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed..

the error was in the PayLoad args..

> ```
>  <args>
>     <arg xmlns:echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org"
>     evaluator="xml"
>     expression="//in"/>
> </args>
> ```

Thank you

Regards
Claudio